# why inline java-script inside XSL doesn't include in server side XSLT transformation?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have below piece of code in one of the xsl file in my project

```
<xsl:template name="javascript">
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function toggleDisplay(item)
    {
         //dummy function, actual code removed            
    }

</script>
</xsl:template>
```

when xslt transformation is done on sever side in java this java-script function will not get included in resulting html output. there is separate js file which will be included in case of server side XSLT transformation. since I am new to XSLT I am not able to understand through code how it is skipping the java script function in XSL file while applying transformation on server side. any direction/help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Well all you have done is shown a named template, unless it is called somewhere else it will do nothing. So please post a minimal but complete sample of XSLT and input XML, output you get and output you want to allow us to understand and reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MartinHonnen this template is not explicitly called inside xsl but when xsl transformation is done at browser side browser is including the JavaScript in HTML output whereas if transformation is done at server end JavaScript is getting skipped. Since my xsl and XML files are very huge & complex I cannot paste the code here sorry for that.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I got the issue, actually on client side one extra wrapper xsl was getting sent which has code to invoke JavaScript template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your template is a name template, it will not be output unless you call it.
You should call your template when you want to use it with a call-template instruction:

```
...
<xsl:call-template name="javascript" />
...
<xsl:template name="javascript">
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function toggleDisplay(item)
      {
      //dummy function, actual code removed            
      }
   </script>
</xsl:template>
```

Otherwise, if you want to output your script element when you encounter a "javascript" element in the xml source document, then you should use the **match** attribute:

```
...
<xsl:apply-templates select="javascript" />
...
<xsl:template match="javascript">
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function toggleDisplay(item)
      {
      //dummy function, actual code removed            
      }
   </script>
</xsl:template>
```